# Date range validator

Tags: javascript, datetime, validation

I have some code which works fine. First, it checks that dates format are valid and then, checks that first date is lower than second date. I had to use free input text and custom validator because multiple date formats are supported such as quarter number (2014 Q1) etc.

But I find my code too long for what it's doing. Any advice on code improvement ?

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/franchez/E6eUN/46/)

```
function check_handler(){
var from = $('#zeDateFrom').val(), to = $('#zeDateTo').val(); 

if(adu_date_format(from) && adu_date_format(to)){
    if( check_date_period(from.trim(), to.trim()) ){
        alert('OK');
    }
    else alert('Start Date must be lower then End Date.');      
}
else{
    alert('Please use a valid date format. For your information, valid formats are:\ndd/mm/yyyy  (e.g 11/12/2011)\n yyyy  (e.g 2010)\n mm/yyyy  (e.g 11/2009)\n and yyyy qq (e.g 2012 Q2).');
}    

}   

function check_date_period(from, to){  
  var result = false;
  var yearFrom, yearTo, monthFrom, monthTo, dayFrom, dayTo;

  // 0) If something to compare...
  if(from==""||to=="") return true;

  // 1) Test if input is type year only
  if(from.length==4){
      yearFrom = from; monthFrom = 1; dayFrom = 1;
  }
  if(to.length==4){
      yearTo = to; monthTo = 12; dayTo = 0; // 0 for last day of month
  }

  // 2) Test if input is type year[space] quarter

  var mySplit = from.split(" ");
  if(mySplit.length == 2){
    yearFrom = mySplit[0];
    dayFrom = 1;
    if(mySplit[1]=='Q1'){
        monthFrom = 1;
    }
    if(mySplit[1]=='Q2'){
        monthFrom = 4;
    }
    if(mySplit[1]=='Q3'){
        monthFrom = 7;
    }
    if(mySplit[1]=='Q4'){
        monthFrom = 10;
    }
  }
  mySplit = to.split(" ");
  if(mySplit.length == 2){
    yearTo = mySplit[0];
    dayTo = 0;
    if(mySplit[1]=='Q1'){
        monthTo = 3;
    }
    if(mySplit[1]=='Q2'){
        monthTo = 6;
    }
    if(mySplit[1]=='Q3'){
        monthTo = 9;
    }
    if(mySplit[1]=='Q4'){
        monthTo = 12;
    }
  }

  // 3) Test if input is type month/year
  mySplit = from.split("/");
  if(mySplit.length == 2){
    yearFrom = mySplit[1]; monthFrom = mySplit[0]; dayFrom = 1;
  }
  mySplit = to.split("/");
  if(mySplit.length == 2){
    yearTo = mySplit[1]; monthTo = mySplit[0]; dayTo = 0; // 0 for last day of month
  }

  // 4) test if input is type dd/mm/yyyy
  mySplit = from.split("/");
  if(mySplit.length == 3){
    yearFrom = mySplit[2]; monthFrom = mySplit[1]; dayFrom = mySplit[0];
  }
  mySplit = to.split("/");
  if(mySplit.length == 3){
    yearTo = mySplit[2]; monthTo = mySplit[1]; dayTo = mySplit[0];
  }

  // FINALLY: Compare dates
  // Note: 00 is month i.e. January
  monthFrom--;
  if(dayTo!=0) monthTo--;
  var dateOne = new Date(yearFrom, monthFrom, dayFrom); //Year, Month, Day
  var dateTwo = new Date(yearTo, monthTo, dayTo); //Year, Month, Day
  //alert(dayFrom+'/'+(monthFrom-1)+'/'+yearFrom+'---------'+dayTo+'/'+(monthTo-1)+'/'+yearTo)
  //alert(dateOne+'-'+dateTwo);
  if (dateOne < dateTwo) {
    result = true;
  }

  return result;
}


function adu_date_format(text){
  var result = false;

  // 0) If something to test...
  if(text=="") return true;

  // 1) Test if input is type year only
  if(text.length == 4){
    if(text >= 2000 && text <= 2030)
      result = true;
  }

  // 2) Test if input is type year[space] quarter
  var mySplit = text.split(" ");
  if(mySplit.length == 2){
    if((mySplit[0] >= 2000 && mySplit[0] <= 2030) && (mySplit[1].length == 2 && mySplit[1] >= 'Q1' && mySplit[1] <= 'Q4'))
      result = true;
  }

  // 3) Test if input is type month/year
  mySplit = text.split("/");
  if(mySplit.length == 2){
    if((mySplit[0] >= 1 && mySplit[0] <= 12) && (mySplit[1] >= 2000 && mySplit[1] <= 2030))
      result = true;
  }

  // 4) test if input is type dd/mm/yyyy
  mySplit = text.split("/");
  if(mySplit.length == 3){
    if(mySplit[2] >= 2000 && mySplit[2] <= 2030)
      result = true;
  }
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What jumps me most about this code is that all you do is in 2 functions.

consider moving your "parsing" operations to separate functions, one for validating the format required for parsing and one for the actual parsing:

```
function isValidQuarterInput(datestring){
   return datestring.split(" ").length == 2;
}

function parseQuarterInputToMonth(datestring){
    var mySplit = datestring.split(" ");
    //move your Q1,Q2,... mapping here
}
```

---

then in check_date_period() you can just call the following

```
if(isValidQuarterInput(from)){monthFrom = parseQuarterInputToMonth(from);}
// this is the alternative ternary operator
monthTo = isValidQuarterInput(to) ? parseQuarterInputToMonth(to) : monthTo;
```

your `var result = false` is unnecessary, as you never use it elsewhere, you can just do the following for return:

```
return dateOne < dateTwo;
```

---

I personally would set a `boolean wasParsed` to be set to true on correct parsing of one input to jump to the `new Date()` part. This can potentially save execution time, but that's minor. You would have to move the parsing in the following order though:

```
var wasParsed = false;
if(from.length==4){
  yearFrom = from; monthFrom = 1; dayFrom = 1;
  wasParsed = true;
}

if(!wasParsed){
   if(isValidQuarterInput(from)){
      wasParsed = true;
      monthFrom = parseQuarterInputToMonth(from);
      yearFrom = from.split(" ")[0];
      dayFrom = 1;
   }
}

if(!wasParsed){
  //here is the full date parsing
}
var dateOne = new Date(yearFrom, monthFrom, dayFrom); 
wasParsed = false;
//repeat with to
```